# Estimation of a vector with a big covariance matrix

Tags: estimation, covariance, covariance-matrix, vector

I have a Gaussian vector with a known covariance, given by a Covariogram (covariance function). Inverting this matrix (let's say of size 5000x5000 and above) is not reasonable.

Is there any known method to do estimation (or similar) where the covariance function is known but is very large and inverting it, or even storing it in its complete form, is impractical?

For instance, let $Y=X+N$ be some vector where $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\Lambda)$ and $N\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2I)$ are independent Gaussian vectors (where $X$ is non-stationary in general), and I would like to obtain $\hat{X}=\arg\max_{X}P(X|Y)$. Then, normally, I would get some equation with $\Lambda^{-1}$ which I would like to avoid.

Comment: Could you explain why you need to invert this matrix? What are you trying to estimate? (Many statistical algorithms that exploit information in covariograms do not require inversion of the matrices.)

Comment: For example if I want to do MMSE or MAP estimation for a large Gaussian vector, the naive approach required inversion. Can you please comment on one of the algorithms that doesn't require it?

Comment: Kriging (which is prediction) does not require inversion.

Comment: As far as I can see, Kringing is used for interpolation, not for estimation... What if I have noisy measurements and I would like to estimate with a Gaussian prior?

Comment: As I said, kriging is a *predictor*.  Your comments are so vague and general that I do not understand what you are really trying to do, and so cannot offer any further suggestions. Let's get back to your original question: if you would edit it to explain in more detail why you think you need to invert this matrix, it will allow your readers greater scope to offer creative answers that address your needs.

Comment: I am sorry, and I have added a general example for my original question.

Comment: What do you mean by 'inverting a 5000x5000 matrix is not reasonable'? I tried on my Mac laptop, and it takes like 1 second to invert a 5000x5000 matrix?

Comment: @Hugh In the process of Kriging one has to create and then invert such a matrix once for each pixel in an image.  Your laptop would take hours even for a moderately detailed results.